# What's the security risk of using xpath?

Tags: security, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, xpath

I'm trying to add an XML column to one of my critical tables in order to save sensitive data. I can't query over these xml records using Entity Framework, so my plan is to query over them using Stored Procedures contains xpath queries, then call SPs by Entity Framework.

I don't know about security *risks of xpath* and *xpath injection*. Any experience about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't trust the user to supply an arbitrary XPath expression, then don't trust them to supply a string that you substitute into an XPath expression using string concatenation. Use an XPath expression containing external variables (parameters), and allow them to supply the parameter values. (Not all XPath APIs allow this, and I'm afraid I have no idea what Entity Framework is).

Comment: Example [link](https://www.fortify.com/vulncat/en/vulncat/dotnet/xpath_injection.html)